# ctable frame color with named color

Tags: color, ctable

I'm using [`ctable`](https://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ctable/ctable.pdf) and I would like to have a frame around tables matching the main color of the document. The problem is that [`ctable`](https://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ctable/ctable.pdf) has the property `framefg` that accepts the RGB values of the color, like so

```
\ctable[framefg = 1 0 0]{...
```

This while very nice does not allow me to simply put `framefg = red` for example. The following is what I would like to be able to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maincolor}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\begin{document}
\ctable[%
  caption = Testing the frame color,
  framerule = 1pt,
  framefg = maincolor,
  framesep = 10pt
]{cc}{}{%
  \FL
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Header}\ML
  a & b\NN 
  c & d\LL
}
\end{document}
```

In the resulting PDF below the table there appears

`maincolor=“relax0¿0 1“XKV@tempa@toks0¿0 1–XKV@prefix0¿0 1,XKV@fams0¿01 0pt`

while the error given is

```
Undefined control sequence. \XKV@resa ->\@nil
Undefined control sequence. \XKV@for@n ...ndafter \XKV@f@r \fi #2{#3}#1,\@nil
Extra \else. ...ter \expandafter \XKV@wh@list \else 
                                                  \def \XKV@tfam {}\expandaf...
```

and some more.

I have then gone to read the source of [`ctable`](https://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ctable/ctable.pdf) and found on page 12

```
34\def\@CTfgcolor#1 #2 #3={%
35\definecolor{@CTframefg}{rgb}{#1,#2,#3}
36\def\@CTfgactual{@CTframefg}}
```

basically answering my question as to why it doesn't work. I then tried (naively since I didn't really know if it would work) to redefine `@CTframefg` to my color like so, in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\colorlet{@CTframefg}{maincolor}
\def\@CTfgactual{@CTframefg}
\makeatother
```

and commenting out the `framefg` option in the `\ctable` call earlier. The document compiled succesfully but the frame color was the default black, not the one I was expecting.

Are there any workarounds to this? I really would like to use a named color since I am trying to create a template for many documents, where I would just need to change the one definition of `maincolor` and have the whole document follow it.

Comment: Very good your question....and also your comment into the answer :-)...and greetings from Sicily :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add such a key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\makeatletter
\define@key{suCT}{framefgcol}{\@dfltCTfgcolorcol#1=}
\def\@dfltCTfgcolorcol#1={\colorlet{@dfltCTframefg}{#1}}%
\def\@CTfgcolorcol#1={%
  \colorlet{@CTframefg}{#1}%
  \def\@CTfgactual{@CTframefg}}
\define@key{CT}{framefgcol}{\@CTfgcolorcol#1=}  
\makeatother

\definecolor{maincolor}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\setupctable{framefgcol=maincolor}
\begin{document}
\ctable[%
  caption = Testing the frame color,
  framerule = 1pt,
%  framefgcol = maincolor,
  framesep = 10pt
]{cc}{}{%
  \FL
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Header}\ML
  a & b\NN 
  c & d\LL
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You sir are fantastic, that works beautifully! I definitely would not have thought about creating a new key. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just incurred in another problem. If I use `\setupctable{framefgcol=maincolor}` I get the error `Paragraph ended before \@dfltCTfgcolor was complete` while if I use that key as an optional parameter to `\ctable` no error is raised. Since I would like to setup all tables to have this behaviour, any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @gjkf My bad, I should have tested it. Fixed it now.

Comment: No worries, thank you so much, I will later implement it into my document and in case of other problems I will report them. In any case, thank you a lot.

Comment: @gjkf You're welcome! (And please let me know if there are further issues.)